# Jinja2 variables in bokeh

Tags: python-2.7, bokeh

I'm trying to pass some variable to a bokeh document which renders a Jinja template.

The code is:

```
curdoc().template = template
curdoc().template_variables["testvar"] = "cia"
curdoc().add_root(row(p1,p2))
```

If I don't use variables at all in the template and don't try to access them via template_variables all works fine, but with the code above I get the error:

```
curdoc().template_variables["testvar"] = "cia"
AttributeError: 'Document' object has no attribute 'template_variables'
```

The command I use to start the application of course is:

```
bokeh serve  --show myapp
```

Where do I do wrong?

Thanks,
gian

Answer (score 1):

`template_variables` is a relatively new feature added in `0.12.4`. You need to upgrade to a newer Bokeh version than whatever you have currently installed.