# Bokeh: add a grid of information below a plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization, bokeh

I have the plot below that I'm currently working on. It describes the movement of a certain product inside a warehouse.

[image: movements chart]

With this plot I also have a dictionary with lots of information about the product (unit cost, lead time, stock level and so on). I wonder if there is a way to also plot this information like a grid below the chart. The desired output would be something like:

[image: desired output]

I've searched for something like this, but the only thing more or less related that I've found was the possibility for `bokeh` [to plot a table as a widget](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/examples/interaction_data_table.html). But the output is something totally different:

[image: table widget sample]

If someone has an answer using or not the `bokeh` library, I appreciate the help :)

My actual code is:

```
p = figure(plot_width=640, plot_height=360, x_axis_type="datetime")
source = ColumnDataSource(df)

p.vbar(x='DT', top='STOCK', width=pd.Timedelta(days=1), source=source, fill_alpha=0.4, color='paleturquoise')
p.vbar(x='DT', top='SOMA_ENTRA', width=pd.Timedelta(days=1), source=source, fill_alpha=0.8, color='seagreen')
p.vbar(x='DT', top='SOMA_SAI', width=pd.Timedelta(days=1), source=source, fill_alpha=0.8, color='crimson')

hline = Span(location=0, line_alpha=0.4, dimension='width', line_color='gray', line_width=3)
p.renderers.extend([hline])

show(p)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions that I am using for similiar tasks:

1. Add a [Div widget](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#div) to your bokeh layout and insert the appropriate HTML Code for your table there. (You can create HTML code for a table for example with [pandas style method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html).)
2. [Customize the bokeh template](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#standard-template) and pass template variables for your addtional/customized content. ([Jinja2 variables in bokeh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896337/jinja2-variables-in-bokeh))

Comment: A third option is to create a new custom extension widget.